# Distinguish features inside a cluster with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, clustering

Based on the OpenLayers [Dynamic clusters example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/clusters-dynamic.html) to tried to implement tooltips on feature mouseover. This works fine for unclusterd icons, but not for the ones which are too close to each other and so are spiderfied.

[image]

I can't figure out how to distinguish by the features as the have the same source and style. Actually I would need to replace the array index 0 of [line 262 of the forked example](https://codesandbox.io/s/clusters-dynamic-forked-ywerdk?file=/main.js:7428-7448) with the index of the actual mouseovered feature:

```
tooltip.show(event.coordinate,"<p>" + spiderFeatures[0].get("BAUJAHR") + "</br>" + spiderFeatures[0].get("LEISTUNG") + "kW</p>");
```

Comment: You could find the nearest original feature using `vectorSource.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(event.coordinate)` https://codesandbox.io/s/clusters-dynamic-forked-egheub

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. But in order to make it more clear I would need the tooltip to appear over the icons and not over the cluster. That's why I tried to set the parameter *spiderfied* and use it in `pointermove`...

Comment: To reflect the real feature position set to tooltip coordinate to `spiderFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()` instead of the event (pointer) coordinate.

Comment: They seem to have the same coordinates as the cluster feature, see https://codesandbox.io/s/clusters-dynamic-forked-ywerdk

Comment: And any strategy how to handle with features with the exactly same coordinates as getClosestFeatureToCoordinate wouldn't work?

Comment: The only problem I could see is some of the features can be outside the radius of the cluster style (style radius was 20 but the cluster distance is 35)  so hover does not detect them.  Adding a transparent buffer to the style fixes that https://codesandbox.io/s/clusters-dynamic-forked-egheub?file=/main.js

Comment: `spiderFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()` gives back the coordinate of the cluster feature, any chance to get to the unspiderfied icon position so the popup can be drawn above each icon? Or would I have to need to move it manually with the same calculation used to move the icon in the first place?

Comment: `spiderFeature` is a feature within the cluster, `features[0]` is the cluster.  As you hover over the cluster `spiderFeature` changes and the popup position and text changes with it.  If you only want the text to change position the popup at center of the cluster `features[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()`.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, everything you commmented is right. I accidently did call `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate` on `clusterSource` instead of `vectorSource`, and so it didn't work out. Could you convert your comment into an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the nearest original feature using `vectorSource.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(event.coordinate)`.

To reflect the real feature position set to tooltip coordinate to `spiderFeature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()` instead of the event (pointer) coordinate.

Some of the original features can be outside the radius of the cluster style (style radius was 20 but the cluster distance is 35) so hover does not detect them.  Adding a transparent buffer to the style will fix that.

https://codesandbox.io/s/clusters-dynamic-forked-egheub?file=/main.js